# Read value of ebx register in Rust with inline assembly ("rbx is used internally by LLVM and cannot be used as an operand for inline asm")

Tags: rust

I'm writing Rust code and need to get the value that is currently stored inside "ebx" register (x86).

My code [0] looks like this:

```
#![feature(asm)]

fn main() {
    let ebx: u32;
    unsafe { asm!("", out("ebx") ebx) };
    println!("current value of register ebx is: {}", ebx);
}
```

The error code from rustc 1.54.0-nightly is:

```
invalid register `ebx`: rbx is used internally by LLVM and cannot be used as an operand for inline asm
```

The only working workaround I found is the legacy way:

```
unsafe {
    llvm_asm!("" : "={ebx}"(ebx) : :);
}
```

Is there a way to achieve the desired functionality with the new `asm!` macro?

PS: Due to my research I came across this: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/84658. But it still doesn't offer a nice and simple solution.

[0] https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8d0a322236cce1efbebedccc40ddbf71

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can move it to another register.

```rust
#![feature(asm)]

fn main() {
    let ebx: u32;
    unsafe { asm!("mov {:e}, ebx", out(reg) ebx) };
    println!("current value of register ebx is: {}", ebx);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to wrap any actual manipulation of `ebx` in a `"push ebx", ..., "pop ebx"` (or `rbx` or ...)